# How to Place two Date Pickers in between Show entries and Search Box in DataTable

Tags: datatable, datepicker

I want to have 2 date pickers in between Show Entries and Search box into dataTable. 
The two datepickers retrieve data from a server.

```html
<script>
   $('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
    } );
 
    $("div.toolbar").html('Start Date: <input type="date" name="Startdate">End Date: <input type="date" name="Enddate">');
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Please share the code you you tried so far, so people can help you much more easily and clearly..

Comment: Like @JithinScaria said, please edit your question to include code and maybe the server endpoints. Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service